# App expires after 24 hours in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to make an android app in Xamarin Studio but when i run ,it show a messge "Built with evaluation software. The build will only work for 24 hours".
And after 24 hours app does not work. How can i resolve it?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: he's using the *trial* version, not the free version. The trial version has a 24h time limit (it's a trial after all). He can either buy a license (Business), or downgrade to the free version (called Starter).

Comment: @Rolf yes, I see that "Starter" option available these days - that's cool! Thanks for pointing out, my trial ran out months ago and haven't bothered to play with Xamarin since then. Altho do sometimes still wear the TShirt. (and still suggest OP takes advice in [CDRosos' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29340109/383414))

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your solution before building it.

Xamarin Studio does not take into account the license used to build your app when rebuilding, so if nothing else has changed, just building the app will in fact do nothing at all.

[source](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8714/trial-executable-has-expired-24-hours-limit-is-this-true-even-after-rebuilding)

Comment: I do clean every time but result is same always,it shows same messege and after 24 hours app does not work

Comment: Have you verify that you \bin dir is empty after clean? because Xamarin latest version has a bug with clean action in VS.

Comment: Any way this is what the Xamarin Dev team suggested as a current fix: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8714/trial-executable-has-expired-24-hours-limit-is-this-true-even-after-rebuilding

Answer (score 1):

This means that you try to use a version of the xamarin that is not free and the trial period has expire, how many kbs are your dlls along with third party libraries and components? if they are more than 64kb then you cannot use the free edition and you have to buy a license.

If you are a student they have a great deal of 100$ for the professional edition.

Check also this thread on xamarin forum about how the 64Kb limit is calculated http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2912/xamarin-starter-edition-build-limits/p1